# Cannot update inserted rows

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I can't update inserted rows until I restart my node.js application.
I use INSERT statement within `SELECT` query if that is important.

```js
var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO moneyset (userID, money, lastDaily, answer) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
stmt.run(user.id, 0, 'Not Collected', null);
stmt.finalize();
```

In the next scope in the same event listener I use

```js
db.run(`UPDATE moneyset SET answer = '${answer}' WHERE userID = '${user.id}'`);
```

But it seems like the second query is never used and not working. 
No errors, all the variables are proper type and not undefined. 
Everything works fine if the row was created before application start, or after the application restart which is not wanted behavior.
Hastebin with the whole snippet: https://hastebin.com/vorepiwube.coffeescript

Comment: You're inserting the row in a callback function passed to `db.get`. You have to use a callback because `db.get` is asynchronous. Which means your `switch` block runs _before_ you're inserting the row. Move the `switch` block inside the callback.

Comment: @ChrisG Moving `switch` block fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for interest on the novice issue

Comment: @ChrisG I only realised that now I can't use my `_voted` variable because of scoping issue (I suppose). It seems like it is never being set and I don't know why.

Comment: Please put relevant code in the question, and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your insert function inside a promise

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.get(`SELECT * FROM moneyset WHERE userID = '${gMember.user.id}'`, (err, row) => {
            if (!row) {
                // var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO moneyset (userID, money, lastDaily, answer) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                // //db.run(`INSERT INTO moneyset (userID, money, lastDaily, answer) VALUES (${user.id}, 0, NULL, NULL)`);
                // stmt.run(user.id, 0, 'Not Collected', null);
                // stmt.finalize();
                money.updateBal(user.id, 1).then(() => { console.log(`Created row for ${user.username}`)});
                resolve(1)
            } else {
                if (row.answer != null) {
                    console.log(row.answer);
                    return gMember.send(`Już wybrałeś odpowiedź do ostatniego pytania **>${row.answer}<**. Poczekaj na następne pytanie.`);
                    resolve(1);
                }else{
                    resolve(1);
                }
            }
          }) 

        }).then(r =>{
           switch (emoji) {
        case '':
            if (_voted) return await messageReaction.remove(user);
            db.run(`UPDATE moneyset SET answer = 'A' WHERE userID = '${user.id}'`);
            voted.set(user.id, messageReaction.message.id);
            break;
        case '':
            if (_voted) return await messageReaction.remove(user);
            db.run(`UPDATE moneyset SET answer = 'B' WHERE userID = '${user.id}'`);
            voted.set(user.id, messageReaction.message.id);
            console.log(_voted);
            break;
        case '':
            if (_voted) return await messageReaction.remove(user);
            db.run(`UPDATE moneyset SET answer = 'C' WHERE userID = '${user.id}'`);
            voted.set(user.id, messageReaction.message.id);
            console.log(_voted);
            break;
        case '':
            if (_voted) return await messageReaction.remove(user);
            db.run(`UPDATE moneyset SET answer = 'D' WHERE userID = '${user.id}'`);
            voted.set(user.id, messageReaction.message.id);
            console.log(_voted);
            break;
        default:
            messageReaction.remove(user);
            break;
    }
        })
```

Comment: This raw code does not seem to work for me. Would need a larger context to implement this, as I do not doubt its correctness.